# Score distribution on Answers

Tags: discussion, answers, reputation

I recently got a [bronze tag badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/276/java?userid=1549476) in [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), and, looking at the requirements, have begun to feel something I think is similar to [Impostor Syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome).

I currently have over 2k rep; however, my highest answer score is `+5`.

I think that this would be understandable were I working in a low-usage tag, but most of my answers are in [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java). My explanation is that I mostly answer questions that are of immediate use to new users of the Java language (by analogy, the site), who lack the ability to upvote, but a more cynical interpretation would be that I have gotten to 2k on trivial rep.

I was wondering if my answering distribution is anywhere close to typical of Stack Overflow, or if it reflects a "trivial rep" tendency on my part.

Comment: I, too, consider(ed) my reputation an inflation of my real skill: some things that shouldn't have been answered have been and some things are answered for the wrong reasons (aka: my top-voted answer). I then started answering more selectively and tried to put more quality in them. If you believe your answers are of good quality then that's all that matters, not the upvotes.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I just visited that answer and resisted the temptation to upvote and exacerbate the problem :-). To your point about quality, I have tried to answer questions on the philosophy that I want to help the questioners unless the question shows no effort or is bad for some other reason. For example, one of the answers I am most proud of is [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27935252/1549476), which is probably of no use to anyone but the OP, because I once had this exact problem.

Comment: I wouldn't worry overly. The very best answers take time to mature. There's a burst of rep initially, as people shoot it out to be fastest gun in the west. This rep burst is about time of day, popularity of tag, whether the question looks like it's an easy win, and a whole bunch of other things. However longer term, you'll get upvotes for your 'good' answers, as people find them via google and upvote you. The 'fastest gun' answers won't have this happening as much.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[Another answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288730/710446) has already given a thorough breakdown of your case specifically, but I'd just like to address your notion of "trivial rep".

I have currently have two answers that have over 100 upvotes, but those are hardly my best answers. Massive piles of upvotes are enabled in large part by the ***domain of the question*** rather than purely the ***quality of the answer***. Those gold-badge answers are simply some of my typical answers that happened to be on specific topics that attracted wide interest.

Meanwhile, I have dozens and dozens of answers that I'm quite proud of (for their carefully crafted explanations or meticulous research) that have seen no more than one or two upvotes because they're on topics that don't command long-term mass attention. If you keep at it for years, you'll eventually stumble into a question or two that garners dozens of upvotes over the next several years. When I wrote my top-rated answers, I didn't finish them and say, "Yes, my masterpiece! Surely *this* will finally get me that Great Answer badge!" Each was just another question that I answered as well as I could, and then people kept discovering it because it matched popular search terms on Google.

I'd say, in general, that a wide spread of helpful answers is vastly more valuable than a one or two spectacularly popular answers. I would be much more satisfied at having solved hundreds of problems than at having struck gold by being the first to answer on a question that later turns out to have celebrity appeal.

Who knows? You may have already written such an answer, and it simply needs time to attract long-term attention from people with voting privileges.

Comment: I wonder if this is the meta effect or just a coincidence. Four of my answers, some dating back a few weeks, were just upvoted, so now the max is +6. 

Anyway, your answer makes me feel a lot better. I'll continue trying to answer as many questions as I have good answers to.

Comment: This is very true, especially in "lower" languages such as Python. While it's a relatively large tag, because of the easily accessible nature of the language and the numerous applications, most answers except for the really masterful/famous/smart ones have low votes. Case in point, one user who specializes in webscraping, @alecxe, has 90k rep, majority of which are from answering VERY specific webscraping questions in Python. His best answer based on upvotes, however, is from a CSV newline character issue. This is not reflective of his real reputation to us Python users though.

Comment: It's pretty common - my highest scoring answers aren't really my "best" answers. (In my opinion). But a detailed answer to a somewhat obscure problem doesn't get as many views, nor is it as obviously right. Where a clear answer to a question that's both interesting but also potentially answerable will mean lots of people look at it, and thus upvote.

Comment: This has definitely been my experience. One of my top-voted answers (for reasons I don't quite understand) is simply an animated GIF demonstrating how to scroll in the iOS Simulator, whereas some answers that I spent days crafting have scores of zero or one.